# What does $\mathcal{X}$ mean at the bottom of integral symbol $\operatorname {E} [X]=\int _{\mathcal{X} }xf(x)\,dx$?

Tags: probability, integration, terminology

section 2.2.7 of "[Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective by Kevin Patrick Murphy](http://noiselab.ucsd.edu/ECE228/Murphy_Machine_Learning.pdf)" gives this formula for [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Absolutely_continuous_case).

${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} [X]=\int_{\mathcal{X} }xf(x)\,dx.}$

There is a $\mathcal{X}$ at the bottom of integral symbol.

Assume $\mathcal{X}$ is a continuous real value random variable, since the book is discussing Machine Learning.

What does that $\mathcal{X}$ mean here? Does it mean "the domain of definition", "support" or something else?

Comment: @Masacroso It's not the domain of $X$. In fact, $\mathbb X$ should be $\mathbb R$ if $X$ is a real continuous random variable.

Comment: @amsmath you are right, my bad. Here $\Bbb X$ is the domain of $f$, not of $X$.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Further_details

Comment: @amsmath Thank you! In your link, "the uniform distribution on the interval [0, ½] has probability density f(x) = 2 for 0 ≤ x ≤ ½ and f(x) = 0 elsewhere", is the interval [0, ½] the support of that uniform distribution, right?

Comment: @baojieqh Exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Bbb X$ (or $\mathcal X$ after the edit) should indeed be the support for $X$, the domain over which the probability density function, $f$, returns non-zero values.

If $X$ is a real-valued random variable, then  $\Bbb X\subseteq \Bbb R$.